# write in file phonegap

Tags: file, cordova

I have seen lots of questions about writing to a file with phonegap on the internet but none of them works for me. I have tried the official phonegap documentation,  but it always return the `error.code 1.` I don't know exactly what does this mean.

I have tried the following solution

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail(){
    console.log('fail');
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    var path = "test.txt";
    fileSystem.root.getFile(path, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);

}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
    $.ajax({
        url:'test.txt',
        success:function(msg){
            console.log('message: '+msg)
        }
    })
}
```

But when the function `gotFileWriter()` is executed the console logs: `write success` but my ajax returns a void document.

I am using the 2.4.0 version, and  when I am trying the documentation 2.4.0 I have this log:

http://pastebin.com/DN8Dyptp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code writes to the file in the file system, whereas the ajax request you are making is in the www folder. Since the test.txt file does not exist in the www folder you are getting that error.

Please use the file reader to read from the file.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader

fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);

Comment: you're right using writ and ride with the doc everithing works, thanks

Comment: @ant where is this file you create located exactly on file system? Can't I pass the exact file:/// path to the file?